# How to best put many images on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to put a lot of images on my Google Sheet but that makes the file so big. What I want is to put a link or something which can redirect us to another window which contains all the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder to put your images in on google drive. If you right click the folder you can press the "get shareable link" button. After you click this you can get a link to the folder which you could put in the sheet.

[image: get shareable link]